# Azure AD Add, not invite, External User as Member, Not Guest

Tags: azure-active-directory

When Azure AD finally moved to the new portal, Microsoft quietly took away the button to add an external user (from another Azure AD or a MS account) directly. Now the only option seems to be to invite users as guests and send them an email link. This also denotes them with a UserType of Guest.

This is prohibitive in a B2C or multi-tenant intranet scenario. We can’t have to email invites around to get people added across directories. Adding users via a B2B spreadsheet import doesn’t seem to get them added as a non Guest either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the Azure AD B2B [invitation options in Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/invitation), you can choose whether or not to send the invitation email, and whether to add the user as a *Guest* or as a *Member*. The [`New-AzureADMSInvitation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azuread/New-AzureADMSInvitation?view=azureadps-2.0) cmdlets from the [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) PowerShell module is just a simple wrapper around this API, so the same capabilities are available in PowerShell.

**Invite a user as member without sending email**

With Microsoft Graph:

```js
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations

{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "user@example.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://example.com",
  "sendInvitationMessage": false,
  "invitedUserType": "Member"
}
```

With Azure AD PowerShell:

```bsh
New-AzureADMSInvitation -InvitedUserEmailAddress "user@example.com" `#`
                        -InviteRedirectUrl "https://example.com" `#`
                        -SendInvitationMessage $false `#`
                        -InvitedUserType "Member"
```

Once the invitation has been created, the user can directly try to sign in to any tenant-specific application they have access to (e.g. https://contoso.sharepoint.com, or https://portal.azure.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or https://yourapp.example.com), using the invited email address as their username.

The first time they do this, Azure AD will automatically detect them as an external user with a pending invitation, and proceed with the required consent prompt to complete the invitation acceptance. Subsequent sign-ins will allow the user to sign in directly. This is described in [Add B2B collaboration guest users without an invitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/add-user-without-invite).